# Is there a way to make dynamic columns in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Basically I was trying to create dynamic column name and value based on db data and formJson data, which looks like below,

```
const dbData=[{
 date: "2022-04-02",
 _id: 12345,
 ins:{
   "1111":"gems@gmail.com",
   "2222":"work@gmail.com",
   "3333":"8877665544"
 }
},
{
 date: "2022-04-03",
 _id: 12346,
 ins:{
   "1111":"gems2@gmail.com",
   "2222":"work2@gmail.com",
   "3333":"8877665566"
 }
}];

const formJson = [{
   id:"1111",
   label:"Personal Email"
},
{
   id:"2222",
   label:"Work Email"
},
{
   id:"3333",
   label:"Contact Number"
}];
```

and the result based on two above json should return ,

```
const result = [{
   "_id": 12345,
   "Personal Email":"gems@gmail",
   "Work Email":"work@gmail",
   "Contact Number":"8877665544"
},
{
   "_id": 12346,
   "Personal Email":"gems2@gmail",
   "Work Email":"work2@gmail@gmail",
   "Contact Number":"8877665566"
}];
```

In object oriented I can make data model which can be mapped dynamically but how to do in js ?

How can key becomes field/column name ?

Comment: You can access to the keys of an Object with Object.keys(myObject) : this will return an array of keys. You can access a property of an object not only with myObject.id but also with myObject['id'] which is usefull when the property has a dynamic name

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for (no error handling added), this is just an example:

```
 const result = dbData.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const data = {
      _id: item._id,
      ...Object.keys(item.ins).reduce((_acc, key) => {
        return {
          ..._acc,
          [formJson.find(info => info.id === key).label]: item.ins[key]
        };
      }, {})
    };

    return [...acc, data];
  }, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It's looks efficient way. Thanks